# Page number in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

I am new user of codeigniter. 
I want to show my output of my data from database as on different pages. 
If total 200 entries 50 in one page and then next and so on .
Please help.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter supports pagination by default.

```
/* Controller */
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
$config['total_rows'] = 200;
$config['per_page'] = 50; 

$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

/* View */

// Print it in the view file
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

More info: [ellislab documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html)